# How do i predict and print out the r2 score for an ann model using keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, prediction

I want to compare the r2 (r square) values for 2 models to determine which one is of a higher predictive accuracy. The 2 models are Ramdom Forest and ANN (using keras). I have successfully gotten the value for my Random Forest algorithm but I cannot seem to figure out this to predict and print out correct values for my ANN algorithm. My data set is for oil production work 2,421 rows and 13 columns. See what I have done so far:

```
# Initialize the constructor
model = Sequential()

# Specifying input layer
model.add(Dense(2000, input_shape=(13,)))

# Add an first hidden layer 
model.add(Dense(1500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))

# third hidden layer
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))


# Add an output layer with one neuron and no activation specified
model.add(Dense(1))

from keras import backend as K

def r2_score(y_test, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square( y_test-y_pred )) 
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square( y_test - K.mean(y_test) ) ) 
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam' , metrics = ['mae', 'mse', r2_score])
                   
epochs = 50

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=200, validation_split=0.3)

pred_train= model.predict(X_train)
print(K.get_value(r2_score(K.constant(y_train),pred_train)))

pred= model.predict(X_test)
print(K.get_value(r2_score(K.constant(y_test),pred)))
```

I got an output of

```
-3170.0261
-1360.6658
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you  think you are doing something wrong? The R^2 score can be negative.

Comment: Please add some info about your data and make sure your code is reproducible. Also include the r2 value computed with sklearn to make sure yours is wrong

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna I don't know how to compute the r2 value with sklearn

Comment: Use [r2_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) from scikit to use it as a comparisson point

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation looks ok. R^2 can be negative for bad models. According to [sckit docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score-the-coefficient-of-determination):

> Best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse).

Note that your definition is almost the same as the used in [`sklearn.metrics.r2_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html), except for the epsilon (they do not mention epsilon in [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score-the-coefficient-of-determination) nor [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf0ea25d6dd034403370fea552b21a6776bef18/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py#L928)), so you can make both equals with just removing it:

```py
def r2_score(y_test, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square( y_test-y_pred )) 
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square( y_test - K.mean(y_test) ) ) 
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot) )
```

Now the output for both implementations should be the same:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score as r2_score_sk

pred = model.predict(X_test)

# current result
print(K.get_value(r2_score(K.constant(y_test), pred)))

# expected one
print(r2_score_sk(y_test, pred)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Please could you hep me fix my model so I get a better r2 score?